# HTML5 Android app - Very Slow

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have created a very simple android app using HTML5 & JQuery Mobile and used phonegap to create android app. My application contains one html page without any assets. It includes jQuery library, jQueryMobile library and jQueryMobile css file.

While running this app on my android phone, I feel that its very slow in response.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What are the specs of that phone?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you port your code from Phonegap to [Titanium](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEgQFjAC&url=http://www.appcelerator.com/&ei=ChlZUYnxBsiNrQfy3IGgAQ&usg=AFQjCNE6ODec3SjXQMtqVytSNYT3Ua3FzA&sig2=5M9yf1ZOSNrJd0WuyLXgHw&bvm=bv.44442042,d.bmk). It's much faster native JavaScript library. This means your code is actually converted to Objective-C or Java rather than running inside a container. That's why its faster than Phonegap.

Read on here:

[**Comparing Phonegap and Titanium**](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/05/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap.html)

But then you would think its them so they will always write good! [`See this Q/A here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9983142/1221203) to know what devs think about this.

Even I ported a application from phonegap to titanium and it has enhanced performance to a benchmark level.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience HTML5 is much slower compare to Native applications. No wonder even Facebook decided to ditch HTML5 apps and went ahead with cool native apps.

If you are running your app on a mid range or entry level Android smart phone then its very much normal to have sluggish animations and ugly looking buttons. Try your JQM app on SIII or SIV it’ll be much better and beautiful.

I heard [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) is much faster compare to JQM but bit difficult to get started. Worth checking out though.